# Can my short proof of Fermat´s Last Theorem be true or is there a serious flaw?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations

A proof of Fermat´s Last Theorem using only Gauss´s Lemma for the roots of monic polynomials with integer coefficients.**

Writing the Fermat equation 
$$a^n + b^n - c^n = (c-p)^n + (c-q)^n - c^n = 0$$ 
with $q < p$ being integers and c taken as an independent variable we get for $n=3$ the polynomial equation 
$$F_3(c,p,q) = c^3 - 3(p + q)c^2  + 3(p^2+q^2)c -(p^3+q^3) = 0.$$ 
In order to preserve the parity always two of $p, q, c$ must be odd and one even. So for an odd $c$ one of $p$ or $q$  must be odd and the other even (first case), whereas for an even $c$ both $p$ and $q$ must be odd (second case). Therefore in both cases $F_3(c,p,q)$ has an even value and might be zero because zero is an even number.

In order to show that this never can be we compare in the first case the roots of $F_3(c,p,q)=0$ to the roots of $F_3(c,2p,2q)=0$, which for an odd $c$ is odd and therefore cannot be zero. Hence $F_3(c,2p,2q)=0$  according to Gauss´s Lemma must have irrational roots which according to Vieta´s formulas for the roots and coefficients of polynomials are twice the roots of $F_3(c,p,q)=0$, which therefore are also irrational. Thus $F_3(c,p,q)$ in the first case never can be zero for an odd $c$.

In the second case $c$ is even and can be written as $2^t*d$, where $d$ is the odd part of $c$ and $t$ is an integer. Rewriting $F_3(c,p,q)$ as $$F_3(2^td, 2^tp,2^tq) = 2^3t [d^3 – 3 (p + q)d^2 + 3 (p^2+q^2)d -(p^3+q^3)] = 0$$ which never can be zero because of the odd value of the expression in square brackets.

With the substitution of $p$ and $q$ by  $2^tp$ and $2^tq$ the roots of  $F_3(2^td,2^tp,2^tq)=0$ are $2^t$-fold the roots of $F_3(c,p,q)=0$ and are irrational according to Gauss´s Lemma. Thus the roots of $F_3(c,p,q)=0$ are also irrational which shows that it in the second case also never can be zero for an even $c$.

Therefore the Fermat equation $a^3 + b^3 - c^3 = 0$ for $n=3$ never can be zero and thus cannot have a solution in integers $a,b,c$. This result can easily be extended to all degrees $n$ being odd primes using the features of the binomial coefficients, especially the fact that for all $n$ there is always an even number of odd coefficients (see, please, https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338819565_Proving_Fermats_Last_Theorem_as_a_Mean_Value_Problem_Title_Proving_Fermats_Last_Theorem_as_a_Mean_Value_Problem_Author).

Comment: [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on Mathjax.

Comment: What do you mean by "the root" of a polynomial in three variables?

Comment: There is only one variable, namely c, and the cubic polynomial equation must have three roots.

Comment: I think people might be more willing to comb through your proof if you improve the formatting, as it’s currently a pretty unappealing wall of text. Some paragraphs and single line equations would go a long way.

Comment: If you consider only $c$ a variable and not $p$ and $q$, I would recommend making that explicit in the notation and/or in the text. Currently I don't see how I could have deduced it from either. Also, the fact that the cubic polynomial equation must have three roots doesn't help me understand what you mean by "the root". In case English is not your native language: The use of the definite article "the" in "the root" implies that there exists exactly one root, to which this expression refers.

Comment: Qwertiops and joriki: Thank you for your critical remarks. See, please, the edited text.

Comment: Interesting attempt, here are just few tips to improve it even further. 1) Distinguish explicitly between a variable of a polynomial (e.g. $F_3(x,p,q) = x^3 - 3(p + q)x^2  + 3(p^2+q^2)x -(p^3+q^3) = 0$) and it's root ($c$ is a root of $F_3(x,p,q) $).  2) "the roots of $F_3(2^td,2^tp,2^tq)=0$" ... this does not make sense as left side is a number, did you mean the roots of $F_3(x,2^tp,2^tq)$? 3) I think you meant $2^{3t}$ instead of $2^3 t$. Apart from that I haven't spot any serious issue in the proof after quick read.

Comment: Also the fact that roots of $F_3(x,kp,kq)$ are k-multiples of roots of $F_3(x,p,q)$ seems to be important, consider stating it as a separate lemma (might help readability?). And one more thing, I am not sure I understand the referrence to Gauss' lemma, but I can see that it is a monic polynomial, and it has no integer roots, than by rational root theorem it must have non-rational roots (irrational or complex, but since it is an odd degree polynomial, at least one irrational root is guaranteed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flaw seems to be in reasoning that if $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ for odd $x=c$ is odd, and so cannot have rational root eventually, then $F_3(x,p,q)$ could not have a rational root for $x=c$ odd. But, $c$ was supposed to be odd in $F_3(x,p,q)$ with $x=c$, while in $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ we expect a root $x=2c$, which is even. You have incorrectly expected that the $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ would have to have its root odd as well.

If you still don't see the flaw, notice that your proof would show that the original equation had no solution, but that is not true. There are known trivial solutions, one is corresponding to $c=1,p=1,q=0$. Here $F_3(x,p,q)=(x-1)^3$ (an odd root), but $F_3(x,2p,2q)=(x-2)^3$ (an even root). Another missed solution is $p=q=c=0$. Try to go through your argument with these specific values and you will see the issue yourself.

Comment: The relation between the roots of F3(x,2p,2q)=0 and F3(x,p,q)=0 can be seen if F3(x,2p,2q)=0 is divided by $2^3$. Then it becomes F3(x/2,p,q)=0 which shows that the roots of  F3(x,p,q)=0 for the same p and q are exactly half of the roots of F3(x,2p,2q)=0 . As F3(x,2p,2q)=0  for x= an odd c has irrational roots, so the roots of F3(x,p,q)=0 must be also irrational.

Comment: Maximum you can show is that odd $c$ cannot be root of $F_3(x,2p,2q)$, but that does not mean its roots are irrational (as in example of $F_3(x,2p,2q)=(x-2)^3$ with $p=1,q=0$, which does not have odd root, yet it has rational root). Overall looking for odd $c$ in $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ is irrelevant (it does not lead to the conclusion, and $c$ is a root of $F_3(x,p,q)$, then $2c$ is a root of $F_3(x,2p,2q)$, and $2c$ is even, so not useful there either).

Comment: What  do you think about the following numerical example with p=2 and q=1? F3(x,2p,2q) =0 gives x1=14.1091..., whereas F3(x,p,q)=0 gives 7.05455..., exactly half of the former. F3(c,2p,2q) cannot have an integer root, because for an odd x=c=7 it has an odd value which cannot be zero. So x=7 is not a root. Besides, this example corresponds to $5^3+6^3 = 7^3 (-2).$

Comment: That example works because $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ has no rational root, therefore $F_3(x,p,q)$ has no rat root. But it is not true that $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ has no rational root BECAUSE it has no odd root, that does not follow. You would have to rule out possibility of even root as well (which conincidently there is none in this case). For some reason you think that $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ can have only odd roots if any, but as I explained before, if the $c$ was odd in $F_3(x,p,q)$, then the correspoding root in $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ will be $2c$. So if anything, you would need to show that $F_3(x,2p,2q)$ has no even root.

Comment: Really try to write out the example with $p=1,q=0$ and see that argumentation that "$F_3(x,2p,2q)$ has no odd root and so it has no rational root" does not work (because exactly in that case it has no odd root but has even root).

Comment: If I write out F3(x,p,q)=0 for p=1 then I get $(x-1)^3=0$ with the odd root  x=1. Writing out F3(x, 2p,2q)=0 for p=1 gives $x^3-6x^2+12x-8=0$ which for an odd x is odd so cannot have an odd root. But for an even x it is even so might be zero so might have an even root say 2y. Then dividing it by 8 we get $y^3-3y^2+3y-1 = ( y-1)^3 =0$, the root of which is odd and not even. So what?

Comment: You have shown $F_3(x, 2p,2q)$ can have rational roots, so you argument cannot continue as "it has irrational roots, therefore...". I don't think there is more to it.

Comment: As an other possibility I can show the irrationality by substituting c+1 instead of c in F3(c,p,q). If c is odd then c+1 is even and thus F3 for p even and q odd becomes odd and its root will be irrational. Hence the root of F3(c,p,q) must also be irrational, because the two roots differ only by an integer, namely 1.